# LINQ - Group by lambda expression

Tags: linq

Say I have the following:

```
var OrderCounts = from o in Orders
                  group o by o.CustomerID into g
                  select new {
                         CustomerID = g.Key,
                         TotalOrders = g.Count()
                  };
```

How can this be converted to a Lambda expression

Comment: There's really nothing you can convert to a "lambda".  The only thing that could be an explicit lambda is the by o.CustomerID.  Maybe if you detail what you're trying to accomplish, someone can offer some advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var OrderCounts = customers
        .GroupBy (o => o.CustomerID)
        .Select (o => new { CustomerID = o.Key, TotalOrders = o.Count () })
```

Comment: Actually it's orders, not customers ;)

Comment: @Nathan Taylor - THANK YOU for your response -  Also is it true that into g like we had in the query expression is only for query expression, it isn't used for Lamda, correct?